# JavaScript Es6 reference this inside inner function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Es6 classes `this` always refers to the object in which it was created in, even inside an inner function because it does `var _this = this` and any reference to `this` will become `_this`. However what if I need want to reference the context of an inner function within that class?

```
class Body {
    constructor () {
        Hooks.subscribe('', () => {
            // I want this to reference the context that is within this method
            // elsewhere because bind,apply,call sets new context
        })
    }
}
```

How can I refer to the context of `Hooks.subscribe` inside an es6 class?

Comment: So you want `this` to be `Hooks`?

Comment: The behavior of `this` doesn't change within classes, but does change in lambdas

Comment: Fat arrow functions (lambdas) bind the scope to the surrounding scope, so it will probably work if you just use `function() { }`.

Comment: Please explicitly state what value you want to have for `this` inside the function. You express no less than three different wishes in your question: _"context of an inner function"_, _"context that is within this method"_ and _"context of Hooks.subscribe"_. Btw: `this` never refers to a context.

Comment: Of course this refers to the context @zeroflagL what else did you think it meant? Unless I have been using the word context wrong all of this time

Comment: _"An execution context is a specification device that is used to track the runtime evaluation of code by an ECMAScript implementation"_. It's nothing the code can access. `this` is a keyword, its value is a reference to an object most of the time. Often `undefined` in strict mode. If you mean something different by context, that's ok. But context == object seems strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to reference Hooks's `this`:

And also assuming that the `subscribe` function returns the original `hook` object

You can do:

```
class Body {
    constructor () {
        const hook = Hooks.subscribe('', () => {
            // `this` will still reference `Body`'s objects this
            // `hook` will reference the hook object
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"Hooks's this"_ and _"Body's objects this"_? `this` is not something that can be attributed to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using an arrow function `this` is kept in scope from the parent. To reassign this to current scope, remove the arrow function.

```
class Body {
    constructor () {
        Hooks.subscribe('', function() {
            // `this` is now the context of Hooks.subscribe
        });
    }
}
```